# Trouble using 'screen -r' command

Tags: linux

I've got some servers running on my VPS machine. While trying to access them by PuTTY, I was told to enter those consoles by using a `screen -r` command. After typing that, I get a list, but I can't access any machine, don't know why.

[image: PuTTY screenshot]

Am I using the `screen -r` command wrong?

**EDIT:** `screen -r 14177` or `screen -r Lobby` won't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is someone already attached to this session (see `(Attached)`). You could use `screen -d -r ...` to dettach other person first and attach after that.